# SQL Server Recursive Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, recursion

I'm trying to list all files in a virtual directory and it's sub directories. This could be employees in a company with subordinates, this is not a file system. Maybe recursive store procedure may not be the answer.

Scenario:

- Directory Table: `DirId, ParentId`
- Files Table: `FileId, DirId`

`ParentId` is the parent directory and root directory has `parentId = NULL`... think it's self explanatory.

Now the problem... I want a list files that exist in a directory and its sub directories.

For just one directory I would create a stored procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM Files Where DirId = ????
```

So how would I create a stored procedure to include sub directories? At the moment I am using C# code and looping through each directory. I prefer to use a stored procedure... unless you prove me wrong.

Comment: Consider using a [Recursive CTE query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx), perhaps.

Comment: You want to access the file system via SQL Server??? This is _much_ easier and better done via application code. Can you explain what problem this solves by doing so in SQL?

Comment: why do you want to use a stored procedure for a task that is clearly better suited to being performed in code like C# ???

Comment: I was thinking of creating a stored procedure for NTiers to use and just thought i was quicker and more efficient using Stored Procedures. If the general consensus is to use code then that's fine.

Comment: This is NOT a file system!!! More a database entry of files uploaded in particular folders.

Comment: @Rob - re-read your question. It implies accessing the filesystem. If that's not the case, please _edit_ your question to clarify, providing the structure of the tables involved and clarify what database you are using (vendor and version).

Comment: Actually Recursive CTE is exactly what I need thanks @pst.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at using a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Something like

```
DECLARE @Directory Table(
    DirId INT,
    ParentId INT
)
DECLARE @Files Table(
    FileId INT, 
    DirId INT
)

INSERT INTO @Directory SELECT 1, NULL
INSERT INTO @Directory SELECT 2, 1
INSERT INTO @Directory SELECT 3, 1
INSERT INTO @Directory SELECT 4, 2

INSERT INTO @Files SELECT 1, 1
INSERT INTO @Files SELECT 2, 1
INSERT INTO @Files SELECT 3, 2
INSERT INTO @Files SELECT 4, 2
INSERT INTO @Files SELECT 5, 3
INSERT INTO @Files SELECT 6, 3
INSERT INTO @Files SELECT 7, 4
INSERT INTO @Files SELECT 8, 4

;WITH Directories AS (
        SELECT  DirId,
                ParentID
        FROM    @Directory
        WHERE   DirId = 2 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  d.DirId,
                d.ParentID
        FROM    @Directory d INNER JOIN
                Directories p   ON  d.ParentId = p.DirId
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Directories d INNER JOIN
        @Files f ON d.DirId = f.DirId
```

Comment: brilliant thanks. But what about DBAs and their response to this as @maycil mentioned?

Comment: I do not aggree with @maycil. Recursion is fine, as long as you dont have loops. I do aggree that creating your own directory structure in the db doe sseem wrong, but that depends on what your goal with this is.

Comment: @astander - we need to keep a log of who had access to what file was uploaded and downloaded, so we track database entries of all files matching this to the actual file structure. You;re right to question this process, but it is for good reasons :)

Comment: @Rob: recursive CTE is the way to go, and it's the most performance-friendly way to go, too. Anything else hand-coded is most likely to be even harder on performance.

Comment: @marc_s - the answer I wanted to hear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking is not to actually access the file system, but rather you have a directory structure represented in tables in your DB, in which case you can use a recursive CTE something like this:

```
DECLARE @DirId INTEGER
SET @DirId = 1

;WITH CTEFolders AS
(
SELECT FileId, DirId FROM Files WHERE DirId = @DirId
UNION ALL
SELECT fi.FileId, fi.DirId
FROM CTEFolders c
    JOIN Folders fo ON c.DirId = fo.ParentId = c.DirId
    JOIN Files fi ON fo.DirId = fi.DirId
)
SELECT * FROM CTEFolders
```

Here's a good [MSDN reference on recursive CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)

Comment: Correct about the File System.. apolgies. I have re-worded the main section.

Answer (score -1):

Actually recursive is not a good solution. Dba don't want us to use recursive,

You can use this script to get directory and sub directory

```
Select d.FileName, f.* from Files f
left Join  Files fsub on fsub.DirId = f.DirId 
inner Join Directory d on d.DirId = f.DirId
```

the sub directory and directory will list with this script

Comment: Why is recursive not a good solution? Your answer will not give what the OP is asking for

Comment: Good point about DBAs. I'm investigating the issues with CTE,

Comment: @AdaTheDev 7, i think because of performance. Looping in the row record will make busy CPU.

Comment: I was worried about this... and to be honest investigating this with the DBA at the moment. Thanks